# Parse a file under linux

Tags: linux, bash, parsing

I'm trying to compute some news article popularity based on twitter data. However, while retrieving the tweets I forgot to escape the characters ending up with an unusable file.

Here is a line from the file:

```
1369283975$,$337427565662830592$,$0$,$username$,$Average U.S. 401(k) balance tops $80$,$000$,$ up 75 pct since 2009 http://t.co/etHHMUFpoo #news$,$http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/05/23/funds-fidelity-401k-idUSL2N0E31ZC20130523?feedType=RSS&feedName=marketsNews
```

The '$,$' pattern occurs not only as a field delimiter but also in the tweet, from where I want to remove it.
A correct line would be:

```
1369283975$,$337427565662830592$,$0$,$username$,$Average U.S. 401(k) balance tops $80000 up 75 pct since 2009 http://t.co/etHHMUFpoo #news$,$http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/05/23/funds-fidelity-401k-idUSL2N0E31ZC20130523?feedType=RSS&feedName=marketsNews
```

I tried to use cut and sed but I'm not getting the results I want. What would be a good strategy to solve this?

Comment: the only difference I see is from number `$80$,$000$,$` to `$80000`. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, I want to have <time>$,$<id>$,$<retweets>$,$<username>$,$tweed_text$,$link

Comment: The problem is that you have the text `$80000` for dollars, that breaks the rule. It would be better to use another field separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we can assume that there are never extra separators in the time, id, retweets, username, and link fields, then you could take the middle part and remove all `$,$` from it, for example like this:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; @a=split(/\$,\$/); $_ = join("", @a[4..($#a-1)]); print join("\$,\$", @a[0..3], $_, $a[$#a]), "\n"' < data.txt
```

What this does:

1. splits the line using `$,$` as delimiter
2. takes the middle part = fields[4] .. fields[N-1]
3. joins again by `$,$` the first 4 fields, the fixed middle part, and the last field (the link)

This works with your example, but I don't know what other corner cases you might have.

A good way to validate the result is to count the number of occurrences of `$,$` is 6 on all lines. You can do that by piping the result to this:

```
... | perl -ne 'print scalar split(/\$,\$/), "\n"' | sort -u
```

(should output a single line, with "6")

Comment: This works perfect! After testing your code I have 6 occurrences of '$,$' per line. Thank you.